# ANT & MSBUILD - build process won't fail if errors

Tags: ant, msbuild, cruisecontrol

When running msbuild.exe with ANT's exec task, errors in the .net code do not result in the build process failing.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 4):

I use Nant to run some MSBuild tasks.  Every time I use the `failonbuild` attribute of that task, it fails for me.  Looking at Apache's documentation for Ant, it would appear the same attribute is there as well. Are you using this attribute?

Comment: I assume that you mean "If I use the failonbuild attribute of that task and msbuild fails, then the build process fails for me."

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at a solution and used `Exec`'s `failonerror`, works like a charm.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted in so others in the future can easily find it also. Glad that it is working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

What do you let the msbuild task do ?

When I used NAnt previously, I used the  task to build a VS.NET solution.

Right now, I'm not using NAnt anymore, I use msbuild instead. :)